# Php file upload and conversion

Tags: php, file-upload, mime-types, file-conversion

How do I convert media file types to their generally accepted type (e.g audio -> mp3) php, I have done so many google searches and can't find anything.

Does doing this remove malicious codes from the uploaded media file?

What's a secure way to determine file type ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [SoX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoX)

exec('sox /your/audiofile.foo /output/audiofile.mp3');